# How to use _.where(list, properties) to get inner array as property?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have JSON structure as below

```js
var listOfPlays = classRoom: [
    {
        title: "Dollhouse",
        femaleLead: true,
        student: [
            { name: "Echo", role: "doll" },
            { name: "Topher", role: "mad scientist" }
        ]
    },
    {
        title: "Dr. Horrible's Sing-Along Blog",
        student: [
            { name: "Billy", role: "mad scientist" },
            { name: "Penny", role: "love interest" }
        ]
    }
]
```

I know basic about _.where in Underscore.js that it will Looks through each value in the list, returning an array of all the values that contain all of the key-value pairs listed in properties.

For example `_.where(listOfPlays, {title: "Dollhouse"});` this will return me an object whose title is "Dollhouse", but how would I get an object base on **student** array's value? from `listOfPlays`?

I am looking for something like:

```js
_.where(listOfPlays  , {student: [name : "Echo"]});**
```

Comment: `[name : "Echo"]` is not valid in JS. Did you mean `[{name: "Echo"}]`? (It still won't work, AFAIK, but it at least isn't a syntax error.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way `_.where(listOfPlays , {student: [name : "Echo"]});` you are looking for does not work anymore in the new version.

You can use:

[_.filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) that looks through each value in the list, returning an array of all the values that pass a truth test (predicate)

[_.some](http://underscorejs.org/#some) that returns true if any of the values in the list pass the predicate truth test.

```js
var listOfPlays = [{
    title: "Dollhouse",
    femaleLead: true,
    student: [{
        name: "Echo",
        role: "doll"
      },
      {
        name: "Topher",
        role: "mad scientist"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "Dr. Horrible's Sing-Along Blog",
    student: [{
        name: "Billy",
        role: "mad scientist"
      },
      {
        name: "Penny",
        role: "love interest"
      }
    ]
  }
]

var output = _.filter(listOfPlays, function(item) {
  return _.some(item.student, {
    name: "Echo"
  });
});
console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```